# Web deployment task failed. ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy my Bot to azure. I have created it in azure and i downloaded the source code. But now im trying to deploy it again i'm getting the error on the title. I got all the credentials correct because i wrote it down before. This is the error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("dotnetfpbot.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)
>   Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator.
>   Error details:
>   Connected to the remote computer ("dotnetfpbot.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.    AzureBot        0

If ever my username or password is wrong is there a way to change them?

Comment: Are you using the deployment username and password from the deployment profile or your Azure account username and password?

Comment: I'm using the microsoft appID and password when i first created the bot in azure portal sir.

Comment: Alright, well you need to use the publish/deployment profile credentials. Normally Visual Studio should do that for you..

Comment: It's okay now. I went to azure and clicked "get publish profile" and theres a password there. I used that password and it logged in successfuly. Now i can publish the bot but how can i publish it back to it's slot in azure portal?

Comment: I first created it in azure and downloaded the source code but now i can't deploy it back even after successfuly publishing it in visual studio.

Comment: Use the publish profile you downloaded, and import it into the Visual Studio project.  It will ensure that when you publish it publishes to the existing web application.

Answer (score 4):

please delete the publish profiles and rebuilt them by going through the wizard again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Sign in to your Azure account and hit 'get publish profile' at the top of the dashboard after you click into your project and you can send it to Notepad. Much stuff there. It all repeats; It is userPWD="the long password is here"

Answer (score 2):

Go to Function App's Configuration/General Settings. On the page set Basic Auth Publishing Credentials to On, Save.

[image: Basic Auth Publishing Credentials has to be set to "On"]

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me today, Even if I get the publishing profile from Azure App Service.

All I did was update my Visual Studio to the latest which is as of this moment is 17.6.0 from 17.5.X

Comment: Thank you so much. Updating visual studio solved this problem from my end.

Answer (score 0):

[Go to side menu configuration/General Settings and set the SCM Basic Auth Publishing and FTP Basic Auth Publishing 'On'][1]

Comment: It looks as though you were trying to include an image, yet no image came through. Can you [edit] your post and try again?